# How to GET data but preserve link array

Tags: html, forms, get

Let's say I have index.php?couple=old and I want to GET new data (search all couples that are "old" but get new data) for example

```
<form action="index.php?couple=old" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search" >
<input type="submit" name="search_btn" />
</form>
```

And someone enters keyword "Smith" it should be index.php?couple=old&search=Smith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`couple` must be a variable to pass, otherwise PHP does not store it as part of `$_GET`.

You need:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="couple" value="old" />
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" name="search_btn" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe little bit more better solution (if you have couple of parameters you want to use).

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<?php foreach($_GET as $name=>$value):?>
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
<?php endforeach;?>
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" name="search_btn" />
</form>
```